# Парсинг (307 редирект)

Tags: php

При парсинге curl'ом, выдает ошибку `307 Temporary Redirect`. Кто сталкивался, как обойти это?

```
header("Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8");

$url = 'http://wowcircle.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);

$uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";


// Params
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// Get html page
$html = curl_exec($ch);

// Close
curl_close($ch);



// Search fragments
$pattern = '~<div id="content-header">(.*?)</div>~is';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $search_res);


// Show searh results
echo $search_res[0]; // print_r($search_res);

// Show html
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($html);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Это не ошибка :)

Answer (score 1):

Следуйте редиректу, также как и при 301 и 302.

Обратите внимание, что там при редиректе кука PMBC ставится:

[image: Заголовки http-запроса, установка куки]

Если не поставить куку, то сервер снова возвращает редирект.

Добавьте еще это:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PMBC=22aa1474f93a37691419631a84b22e6c");
```

Не знаю на сколько долго это будет работать. Если перестанет - то тогда читайте куку и отсылайте её на следующем запросе после редиректа.

Comment: Спасибо, работает:)

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода в одном из рабочих проектов, который запоминает куку на первом запросе и передает её после.
Код написан в традициях ооп, так что интеграция на ваших плечах.

1. устанавливаем колбэк функцию

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, [ &$this, 'headerCallback' ]);
2. тело (я сохранял **PHPSESSID**, вам нужно **PMBC**)

> /**  * Задаем CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION для сохранения кукисов  * @param
>   resource $ch  * @param string $header  * @return type  */

```
protected function headerCallback($ch, $header) {
    $id = $this->getIdByCh($ch);

    $mathes = [ ];
    if ( preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $header, $mathes) == 1 )
    {
        if ( false !== ($str = strpos($mathes[1], 'PHPSESSID')) )
        {
            $session = substr($mathes[1], $str + strlen('PHPSESSID') + strlen('='));
            if ( !isset($this->cookies[$id]['session']) )
                $this->cookies[$id]['session'] = $session;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $mathes[1]);
    }
    return strlen($header); // Needed by curl 
}
```

3. Определите метод getIdByCh, если в дальнейшем понадобиться CurlMulti, иначе можно выпилить.

> /**
>   * Определяем ID чайлда в очереди
>   */

```
protected function getIdByCh($ch)
{
    return array_search($ch, $this->chs);
}
```